# BackgroundWorker access to class level variables

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application with a GUI thread and wish to pass a single long running process to a separate thread, in this case a BackgroundWorker.

The correct way to use background worker would be to enable ReportsProgress and handle WorkerCompleted.  However, are there good reasons to not use a variable instead?

For example :

```
Private threadCompleted As Boolean

Private Function LongWork() as Boolean

    threadCompleted = False
    bkgwWait.RunWorkerAsync()

    Do While Not threadCompleted
       ' Do some screen work
       Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Loop

    ' Carry on in the main thread

End Function

Private Sub bkgwWait_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bkgwWait.DoWork

   '  Call to a web service
   threadCompleted = True

End Sub
```

threadCompleted is declared at class level and used to indicate the worker has finished.  Is this perfectly safe or will it cause issues with lock conditions or overuse CPU cycles?  Or is it just bad practise

Comment: It is an extremely bad practice.  The code snippet cannot clarify why you think you need to make the user interface unresponsive with that while-loop.  The entire point of BGW is to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Ok, the snippet probably doesn't explain the issue very well.  More the point of the question is there a technical issue to accessing class level variables this way?

Comment: There is, you are accessing a variable that is assigned by a worker thread without proper synchronization.  Tends to work by accident, but the .NET memory model provides no guarantee it will always work.  BGW was designed to never have to do that, its IsBusy property is safe for example.  Doesn't make the code any better however.

Comment: You should really describe the actual use case. It looks like you want to set a field's value because you're locking the UI thread, so the `RunWorkerCompleted` is never raised. This could be a *classic* race condition of two threads that are *meant* to cooperate at some level. The assumption that this kind of stuff can be solved setting a `bool` usually requires a complete re-design after a lot of effort has been wasted while trying to fix its misbehaviours.